# Buying a new pc for work, gaming

Tags: gaming, pc, desktop

First of all I already have a laptop, although it's not a very powerfull one, which I got 5 years ago.

That being said, on to the business.

I was aiming for a desktop from this shop:

https://www.chip7.pt/desktop/35176-doit-gamer-i5-8400-chip7-doit-g.html#/9-perifericos-com_perifericos/49-ssd-ssd_240gb/37-grafica-nvidia_gtx_1060_3gb/8-so-sem_sistema_operativo][1]

And I wanted one for work and gaming too.

I'm gonna be playing games like **Gta V**, **League of Legends**, **Minecraft**, **Assassin's creed Origins**, **Battlefield**, **Cod Bo3**, etc

I want a stable one and I have a budget of around 1150€.

I don't have a monitor yet either, so please take that in mind.

I've thought about a mac, but I don't think it's that good for gaming, is it?

I'm a programmer, so I also wanted that pc to be good for programming stuff, like in android studio, or making graphs in python with matplotlib.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where are you located? Do you have a target resolution/refresh rate? Would you prefer a single laptop which can also game?

Comment: "I've thought about a mac, but I don't think it's that good for gaming, is it?" It is infact not optimal for gaming, but it is possible just not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Based on the site you linked and the fact that your marked currency is Euros I'm going to assume you live in Spain, so I've recommended computers that could ship to Spain today.

Your linked computer seemed pretty good, but I thought I could maximize the price point further. The desktops I have recommended are capable of blowing any of the latest triple A games or heaviest application development suites out of the water. **Each recommendation also doubles the amount of RAM in your configuration to a gratuitous 16 GB (DDR4).**

### [MSI Trident 3 VR7RC-405US €934,99 @ Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883152410)

[image: MSI Trident 3 VR7RC-405US]
This is the desktop that I purposely chosen to price match your current selection and beat out it's components. This configuration fits in a powerful **i7-7700** along with a **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060**, with **6 GB VRAM making it VR ready**. It also comes with **1 TB HDD and a blazing fast 256 GB M.2 SATA SSD**. This thing is filled with enthusiast grade goodies so it's probably more than you need, but if you're willing to spend 960€ on your linked system, you might as well buy this and save that 26€ for a nice dinner.

### [ABS Battlebox Essential Vortex Leo €1.036,99 @ Newegg MSRP: €1.381,99](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16883102377)

[image: ABS Battlebox Essential Vortex Leo]
Comes armed with a **i7-8700K which means you'll have additional control for overclocking scenarios**, **a 1 TB HDD**, and **a 240 GB SSD** and the aforementioned **NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB**. In this configuration you're really just paying for that CPU as it is [37% faster according to average user benchmarks](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8700K-vs-Intel-Core-i7-7700/3937vs3887) drastically outperforming the i7-7700 in multi-core scenarios. I don't expect you to actually use the system to a point where the cpu will bottleneck even if you have a i7-7700 so the extra processing power may not go that far for you unless you plan on overclocking as this processor can be pushed much farther than the i7-7700.

---

Now since you said you want to game with your configuration and would like some monitor recommendations, here are two 1920x1080 monitors with gratuitously high response times (1ms).

### [Acer KG1 Series KG221Q €80,99 @ Newegg MSRP: €111,99](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824011095&cm_re=monitor-_-24-011-095-_-Product)

[image: Acer KG1 Series KG221Q]

This is a 21.5" 75 Hz monitor, supports VGA, HDMI, and has 2x2 built in speakers.

### [Acer GN246HL €169,99 @ Newegg MSRP: €171,99](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824009642&cm_re=monitor-_-24-009-642-_-Product)

[image: Acer GN246HL]

This monitor is a 24" 144Hz monitor that supports D-Sub, DVI, HDMI. This monitor would be a real treat to play video games with due to it's super responsive refresh rate and response time, but comes with a pretty hefty price. This is a monitor that will make your friends jealous.

---

### Final thoughts

To keep your system under your 1.150K budget, I think that you should go with the MSI Trident 3 and Acer GN246HL configuration as this make for a very pleasant experience while being under your max budget by 45.02 €.

Comment: Sorry, got to give this a -1. Neither of those prebuilts are great value or well balanced, and the cost is going to vary massively depending where they're located in Europe.

Comment: @JMY1000 In what why do you see the systems as imbalanced? If you feel there is a better answer feel free to post a better one and I will retract mine.

Comment: Overemphasis on CPU compute power and RAM rather than GPU. I will post my own answer once I get back an answer from OP about where they're located so I can get accurate pricing.

Comment: @JMY1000 [the GTX 1060s are by no means weak](http://gpuboss.com/graphics-card/GeForce-GTX-1060) and I felt that they were adequate for the usage case. I avoided some of the newer higher end NVIDIA GPUs because I had heard that their price is being inflated by the crypto market. The way I looked for the computers was based on GTX 1000 series, any i7+ skylake processor (for DDR4 timings). The systems that happened to be the cheapest just so happened to have these processor/RAM pairings.

Comment: In fact here is the [query](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100897449%20601314311%20601314320%20601315061%20601314507%20601314508%20601314514&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&Order=PRICE&PageSize=36).

Comment: Prices are coming down now, and moving from a 1060 to a 1070 or 1070ti is going to be a much bigger jump from an i7 to an i5 with similar clocks. Single core performance is generally much more important than the number of cores in games, and hyperthreading especially rarely makes a difference in games.

Comment: @JMY1000 [The cheapest system available to Spain](https://www.newegg.com/global/es/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883101475) I could find that has at least a 1070 starts at 
€1.120,99. It has a i7-6700 which is more than adequate processor pairing, however, left too small a margin without sacrificing the monitor, although arguably I could relax the response time spec.

Comment: Why force a prebuilt system? Why restrict yourself to looking at Newegg?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79501/discussion-between-bennett-yeo-and-jmy1000).